# PDNS forward unknown entries to another nameserver

Tags: powerdns

currently i´m stuck at the following problem:

We have nameservers for the different networks (172,192,212(external)) and there is a wildcard entry in the forward-zone file which forwards queries for unknown domains from server to server until the external servers ask external dns servers, which is working as expected. But our problem is that when we use the same zone in the different networks, the queries for an unknown entry aren´t forwarded to the next nameserver (different zone) because we defined that the current nameserver is responsible for the zone.

Is there any possibility to forward queries for unknown entries to the next server in the chain ?
All servers consist of an combination of pdns and pdns-recursor (for forwarding queries).

Thanks in advance,
Alexander

[link to image of dns structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC4Pg.png)